# "Save As" Macro (vba) on mac

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

I have some code here that I use to save a .pdf file but instead of saving the specific sheet it's saving all the excel sheets.
I would like to focus on saving one specific sheet.

Hope you guys can help.

```
Sub Save_client()
Sheets("Client Form").ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="/Users/"user"/Desktop/" & Range("A2") & Range("B2") & ".pdf"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `From` and `To` arguments:
This will export just page 2

```
  From:=2, To:=2
```

[ExportAsFixedFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/range-exportasfixedformat-method-excel?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144246)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Thanks that helped! do you also know how to get the sheets on one page?

Comment: I think that is determined by your virtual paper size.

Comment: A4, the excel sheet is 6 pages long.